# Is there a way to install PKI user certs into an HTA Application?

Tags: javascript, ajax, activex, pki, hta

I need to make an AJAX call from my HTA application to a site that requires mutual PKI authentication.  My PKI certs are installed in IE7. I thought that because HTA uses the IE engine that the PKI settings would be carried over to the HTA application -- this is not the case.  Is there a way to install PKI user certs into an HTA Application?

Answer (score 0):

IE does not have its own storage for client auth certificates. They are saved in user's "MY" store. To see what you have in the store, run "certmgr.msc" and look in Personal->Certificates. HTA application shares the same certificates. What error do you get from HTA? IE has setting to not prompt you for certificates if it cannot find a match or it finds exactly one match.